# Looping through object properties of an array and comparing

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I've got an array of objects containing several properties, looking something like this:

```js
[
  {
    "title" = "Test",
    "prop1" = 4,
    "prop2" = 6
  },
  {
    "title" = "Test2",
    "prop1" = 5,
    "prop2" = 7
  },
  {
    "title" = "Test",
    "prop1" = 6,
    "prop2" = 14
  }
]
```

What I want to do, is…

- looping through the objects
- comparing the title, to only have one output per title later on
- sum up the properties of the objects with the same title

So in the end my output would be something like…

- Test, 10, 20
- Test2, 5, 7

I tried to store values in variables, comparing these variables, but this only worked for two sets of data and in my case there can be also five, ten or 15 sets of data with the same title.

Any help appreciated, thanks! :)

*Additional information: I need to access the properties by name, like* `data[1]['title']`

Comment: Lets see the code you tried all these in.

Comment: first of all, create a key-value pair inside the object for apply indexing and looping.

Comment: you can use loadash library  const Titles = _.groupBy(objects, obj => car.title); to get the list grouped by the same title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Array.prototype.reduce` to accumulate the processed entries of the array and by processed I mean finding the element which shares the same `title` by using `Array.prototype.findIndex` and summing the properties other than the `title`:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "title" : "Test",
    "prop1" : 4,
    "prop2" : 6
  },
  {
    "title" : "Test2",
    "prop1" : 5,
    "prop2" : 7
  },
  {
    "title" : "Test",
    "prop1" : 6,
    "prop2" : 14
  }
];
const out = data.reduce((r, e) => {
  let idx = r.findIndex(o => e.title === o.title);
  if(idx >= 0 ){
    r[idx].prop1 += e.prop1;
    r[idx].prop2 += e.prop2;
  }else{
    r.push(e);
  }
  return r;
}, []);
console.log(out);
```